# Jquery Tabs activating in Laravel 5 Web application

Tags: php, jquery, tabs, laravel-5

I am developing a laravel web application with Jquery UI tabs.
here is the screen shot of my page.[image]

I have tabs like

**Basic Information**

**Contact Information**

**Legal Details**

**Business Categories**

**Location**

Tha Five tabs having form and laravel sending the update function for that..When User updates from the **Contact Information** tab, After succesful updation, the page is redirected and loads the first tab like **Basic Information**.

My Update Controller.

```
 public function edit_businessldaction(){

    try {
        $decrypted = Crypt::decrypt(Input::get('ciid'));
    } catch (DecryptException $e) {
         throw new DecryptException("Invalid data.");
    }
    $doaction = DB::table('business')
        ->where('pk_business_id', $decrypted)
        ->update([
            'ci_busns_name' => Input::get('ci_busns_name'),
            'ci_busns_addrs1' => Input::get('ci_busns_addrs1'),
            'ci_busns_addrs2' => Input::get('ci_busns_addrs2'),
            'ci_busns_addrs3' => Input::get('ci_busns_addrs3'),
            'fk_ci_busns_country' => Input::get('ci_busns_country'),
            'fk_ci_busns_city' => Input::get('ci_busns_city'),
            'ci_busns_telephone' => Input::get('ci_busns_telephone'),
            'ci_busns_fax' => Input::get('ci_busns_fax'),
            'ci_busns_web' => Input::get('ci_busns_web'),
            ]);
    if ($doaction)
        return Redirect::to(route('edit_business_view',Input::get('ciid')))->with('cimessage','Legal Details Updated Succesfuly !!');
    else
        return Redirect::to(route('edit_business_view',Input::get('ciid')))->with('cimessage','No changes are made !!');
}
```

URL of the above screenshot page is

**http://localhost/genie-works/devojp/superadmin/edit-business/{id-randomkeyencrypted}**

HTML :

```
 <div id="tabs">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="tabs-1">
 <p> Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci    tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
 </div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<p>eugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.    </p>

</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You could determine the right tab to be be activated by setting it in your blade template. Kindly share HTML code for the tabs

Comment: editted question. added html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a named-route, you can determine the current controller/action by using `Route::is` method in your blade template to activate the current tab.

**Here is an Example that using bootstrap tabs:**

Am using a named-route like so:

```
 Route::get('/edit-business/{id-randomkeyencrypted}',[
    'uses' => 'ContactController@edit_businessldaction',
    'as'   => 'contact.edit_businessldaction'
 ]);
```

Am going to active the right tab by using this:

```
{{ Route::is('contact.edit_businessldaction') ? 'active' : '' }}
```

And activate the right content by doing this:

```
{{ Route::is('contact.edit_businessldaction') ? 'tabname' : '' }}
```

NB: Replace `tabname` with tab content id you wish to activate, e.g: `contact`

In Blade Template

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="contact-info" class="{{ Route::is('contact.edit_businessldaction') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="#contact" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Contact Information</a></li>
  </ul>


<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="{{ Route::is('contact.edit_businessldaction') ? 'contact' : '' }}">...</div>
</div>
```

I believe this will give you an Idea

OR

Alternatively you could return a variable to your view like so:

```
return Redirect::to(route('edit_business_view',Input::get('ciid')))
->with('cimessage','Legal Details Updated Succesfuly !!')
->with('active','business');
```

and later in your view:

```
//For Tab
{{ $active=='business' ? 'active' : '' }}

//For Content
{{ $active=='business' ? 'tabname' : '' }}
```